# Create Sub domain for a particular page

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I know how to create sub domain in cpanel using wildcard, but when user open page.php then sub domain created like

```
page.website.com
```

this can be done .htaccess or some other method ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

<del>with `.htaccess`</del>

<del>DirectoryIndex page.php index.html index.php</del>

<del>Add index.html and index.php after page.php, for fallback reason.</del>

---

with `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)page\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ page.php%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: you mean when someone open the link www.page.website.com, page.php will open ?

Comment: @Adas I just realise you edited your question. Please check again with my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sub domain with your cpanel

1. login cpanel
2. go to domains section
3. click on sub domain
4. enter your sub domain name and then pick the primary domain

5 click on create button

you can also find a step by step video tutorial at

How to Add Sub Domain in CPanel

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sIdcQj8Gm8